# Combine numpy array with TfidfVectorizer as a joint feature matrix in SKLearn

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer, countvectorizer

I have a dataset `input`, which is a list of ~40000 letters (that are represented as strings).

With SKLearn, I first used a `TfidfVectorizer` to create a TF-IDF matrix `representation1`:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
import sklearn.pipeline

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(lowercase=False)
representation1 = vectorizer.fit_transform(input)  # TFIDF representation
```

Now, I want to manually add one feature `representation2` for every letter. This feature should tell the amount of different words compared to all words in a specific letter/string:

```
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
sum_words = np.sum(count_vectorizer.fit_transform(input).toarray(), axis=-1)
sum_different_words = np.count_nonzero(count_vectorizer.fit_transform(input).toarray(), axis=-1)
representation2 = np.divide(sum_different_words, sum_words)  # percentage of different words
```

The array `representation2` is now an array of shape `(39077,)` (as expected). I now want to combine `representation1` and `representation2` into one feature vector `representation`.

I read about using [FeatureUnion](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) to combine two kinds of features in SKLearn, but I am not sure how to correctly use the Numpy array `representation2`as a feature here. I tried:

```
union = sklearn.pipeline.make_union([representation1, representation2])
```

But now I can't use e.g. `union.get_feature_names_out()`, since it throws: `AttributeError: Transformer list (type list) does not provide get_feature_names_out.`

What did I understand incorrectly here?